# Карта интенсивностей (heatmap) в Java

Tags: java, график

Есть двумерный массив с double значениями. На основании этого массива нужно построить карту интенсивностей (heatmap). Есть какое то тривиальное решение или фреймворк с примерами, без многочисленных строк кода? Фреймворками еще не пользовался)

Рекомендации по стороннему софту также приветствуются)

Comment: гугл не помог? по запросу "heat map java" первые 3 ссылки и дальше по желанию

Comment: @Виктор У меня оно не работает :)

Comment: тогда покажите, что вы делали и что именно у вас не работает. + то как хотите, чтобы работало.